# Как при использовании EAV сделать добавление полей по категориям, а не по сущностям?

Tags: база-данных, eav, yii, php, sql

Хочу написать простой интернет-магазин (на Yii). Разумеется, у товаров должны быть произвольно добавляемые поля, для чего используется паттерн Entity-Attribute-Value. Как правильно сделать так, чтобы типы полей привязывались к категориям, а значения - к конкретным товарам?

Т.е., допустим, админ сайта, создавая карточку товара, выбирает категорию (допустим, грубо говоря, "жесткие диски"), и появляются поля, специфичные для данной категории ("объем", "скорость вращения шпинделя" и т.д.), и заполняются конкретно для этого товара. А названия/типы полей должны указываться при создании/редактировании категории, а не товара.

Comment: @zugo, а может быть не городить огород с EAV для [РСУБД](http://goo.gl/CIhCiO), а использовать ["безсхемное" решение](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/extensions/mongodb). Произвольным количеством полей это их "хлеб", кроме того, у той же MongoDB доступен индекс для общих полей (плотный индекс) и часто встречающихся (разряженный индекс).


Уверен, если MongoDB присутствовала на подавляющем большинстве shared-хостингов, то не одна бы CMS не посмотрела в сторону MySQL.

Comment: @romeo, надеюсь ТС не воспримет ваш комментарий как руководство к действию. был бы это ответ, заминусовал бы. (также безапелляционно как и утверждения в комментарии).

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я предложил один из вариантов. Я не противник реляционных БД. Кроме того, ТС спросил, как подобный паттерн реализовать в определенном фреймворке (Yii). При использовании [AR подхода](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-active-record.md) могут возникнуть сложности. И да, EAV я с лёгостью реализовал, используя [указанное расширение](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/extensions/mongodb)

Comment: @romeo, в рамках данного вопроса, в первую очередь хотелось бы услышать какие "сложности могут возникнуть", а не абсолютно альтернативное решение. Вот например, одна [реализация](http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/31/dinamicheskie-atributi-dlia-tovarov-ispolzovanie-eav-v-yii). Думается, не единственная.  
Использование же noSQL в каком-либо проекте должно исследоваться отдельным образом. И считать что mongo могло бы вытеснить с рынка mysql (или другую [р]субд) слишком самоуверенно.  
**UPD** [Для размышления](http://habrahabr.ru/post/231213/)

Comment: > Вот например, одна [реализация](http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/31/dinamicheskie-atributi-dlia-tovarov-ispolzovanie-eav-v-yii) 

@Yura Ivanov, убедили. И, кажется, что я находил эту статью когда-то. Но, три сущности! Одно дело, когда подобное требует логика приложения (к примеру. реализация тегирования через сводную таблицу), а другое - хранить, по сути, схему  БД в отдельной взятой сущности. В Mongo всё в одной коллекции - атрибуты остаются атрибутами.

Comment: >И считать что mongo могло бы вытеснить с рынка...

В моём "хозяйстве" подавляющее большинство проектов на sql и только несколько используют монгу. Я по привычке использую [Mongo References](http://goo.gl/LaAYf5), ибо считаю нелогичным всё сваливать в одну коллекцию. Это к слову, о той хабр-статье,которую я естественно читал. И да,речь шла про CMS,где паттерн EAV в почёте.

Я не хочу ни в коем случае устраивать холивар, и тем более с пеную у рта, что-то доказывать, как,к примеру, [Бартунов (c 42 минуты)](http://www.radio-t.com/p/2014/04/05/podcast-386/). Пусть каждый остаётся при своём мнении

Comment: @romeo, ни в коем случае не холивар. тема просто другая, монго тут ни к месту. имеется в виду, не его использование (вполне возможно, что могут быть удачные реализации интернет-магазинов на монго), а обсуждение его использования не к месту, вопрос о другом.  
зы подкаст прикольный, спс.